# C++ How do I get the next node to appear before the previous in a double linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

For example, my text file reads:

```
A 1
A 3
B
A 2
```

The goal is for the output to be `123`, but I have gotten everything but that.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    char letter;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
    Node(char cc)
    {
        letter = cc;
        next = prev = nullptr;
    }
};

string command;
char parameter;
Node* p = nullptr;
Node* rows[10];
int currentRow = 0;

void main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        rows[i] = new Node('.');
        rows[i]->next = nullptr;
        rows[i]->prev = nullptr;
    }
    
    ifstream input("c:\\temp\\input.txt");
    while (input.peek() != -1)
    {
        Node* c = rows[currentRow];
        c = rows[currentRow];

        while (c->next != nullptr)
            c = c->next;       

        input >> command;
        if (command == "B") {                 // Back Curser
            //Moves curser back
        }
        else if (command == "F") {                 // Forward Curser
            //Moves curser forward
        }
        else if (command == "A")                   // Add char         Done
        {
            input >> parameter;
            Node* newnode = new Node(parameter);
            c->next = newnode;
            newnode->prev = c;
        }
    }
    input.close();

    // display linked list
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Node* t = rows[i]->next;
        if (t != nullptr)
        {
            while (t != nullptr)
            {
                cout << t->letter;
                t = t->next;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

At first I had tried `c = c->prev`, but that did not work, as nothing was reorganized in my linked list.

I also attempted to create a brand new node that was hopefully then filled by the upcoming character, but my logic did not add up to that, and I ran into multiple issues.

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code and see what your debugger says?

Comment: Also, try to reduce that program to an [mre]. Exclude everything you don't absolutely need to reproduce the problem. That helps us analyze the code more quickly and, quite potentially, you to find the error without our help.

Comment: For example you state in your file 'B', but 'B' is nonfunctional in your code. As such, you would, assuming 'A' works correctly, always get 132, in order of the file.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium I have just removed all unnecessary code that does not involve the question.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium I have nothing in the commands of B and F as all previous attempts have been unsuccessful. Which resulted in me asking for help. I have stepped through in the debugger and made attempts based on that and still struggled.

Comment: As a side-note, storing every individual character in a linked list node is problematic for several reasons, but the primary one is memory: every character of text in this program occupies 3 pointers of storage, not including any additional overhead of the allocator. This means (on a 64-bit system) you use at least 24 times as much memory as the actual text being stored. Not only is that wasteful, but it scatters text across your address space and affects cache performance. It also makes things like text searches _etc_ more cumbersome to code. Especially if you need to handle UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @paddy In the course I am currently taking, there is no emphasis on memory usage at all yet. But your information makes complete sense and I appreciate it.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium When I try c->prev->next = nullptr; for my "B" command. I get "12". I lose my 3. How could I get that 3 back and just have it in the front?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the lack of implementation details in 'B', I'll just help you fix 'A' instead.

You see, when moving the cursor back, you are now pointing to an element that already has a 'following node' (`next` is no longer nullptr)

```
else if (command == "A")                   // Add char         Done
{
    input >> parameter;
    Node* newnode = new Node(parameter);
    newnode->next = c->next;               //Link the new node to the previously following node (may be nullptr)
    c->next = newnode;
    newnode->prev = c;
}
```

Without the line I inserted, the previous `next` of `c` becomes inaccessible, leading to a memory leak.